# Python's insert returning None?

Tags: python, list

```
#!/usr/bin/python

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

clean = numbers.insert(3, 'four')

print clean
# desire results [1, 2, 3, 'four', 5, 6, 7]
```

I am getting "None". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mutating-methods on lists tend to return `None`, **not** the modified list as you expect -- such metods perform their effect by altering the list in-place, not by building and returning a new one.  So, `print numbers` instead of `print clean` will show you the altered list.

If you need to keep `numbers` intact, first you make a copy, then you alter the copy:

```
clean = list(numbers)
clean.insert(3, 'four')
```

this has the overall effect you appear to desire: `numbers` is unchanged, `clean` is the changed list.

Comment: I found the solution helpful, thank you. But I was wondering the reason of creating `clean` with `list(numbers)` instead of directly `numbers` whose type is already a list?

Comment: I did say, precisely, "If you need to keep numbers intact, first you make a copy, then you alter the copy".  `numbers` is a list, but unless you make a copy, you'll *alter* that list; and it appears the OP wanted to keep the original intact while making a changed copy.

Comment: As a beginner of Python, I thought just the assignment of variable `clean` would literally make a copy of `numbers` so the following operation on `clean` would keep `numbers` intact.

Comment: @Fredom, no, that's an absolutely crucial issue in Python (and Java, and Javascript, and most other languages today): assignment does **not** make a copy, just adds one more reference to the object on the right-hand side of the `=` sign.  That only matters for mutable objects, but, of course, Python lists (like Java and Javascript arrays) **are** mutable!-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Though it is nothing more than foundation, I found `clean = numbers[:]` and `clean = copy(numbers)` do the same job.

Comment: @Fredom, yep, there are many ways to do a shallow copy (though to call a global named `copy` you need in addition a very peculiar import).  I like the general approach typename(typeinstance) because it works in a very general way (`list`, `dict`, `set`, and many others yet) **and** even when the instance isn't "quite" of the type you're naming, e.g `list(someset)` makes a list with the same items as the set, without any problem or trouble, too.

Answer (score 12):

The insert method modifies the list in place and does not return a new reference.  Try:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
>>> numbers.insert(3, 'four')
>>> print numbers
[1, 2, 3, 'four', 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 3):

The list.insert() operator doesn't return anything, what you probably want is:

```
print numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

insert will insert the item into the given list. Print numbers instead and you'll see your results. insert does not return the new list.