# adding 1 constant value to all sub_list in list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
list1=[[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
```

I want to add a single value "one" to all sublist in the list at index 2

final output should be:

```
list2=[[2,3,"one"],[4,5,"one"],[6,7,"one"]]
```

tried with:

```
for list2 in list1:
    print list2.insert(2,"one")
```

But its showing error as `None`.

Comment: ``list.insert`` does not return anything

Comment: @MikeScotty: list.insert is inserting new list but not adding values in sublist

Comment: Don't say "add" when you really mean "append"... or "insert at index 2"... You're not "adding 1", you're "inserting 'one' at index 2". Very misleading title.

Comment: The `None` is due to `list.insert` being an in-place function. There are many duplicates e.g. [Insert an element at specific index in a list and return updated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-updated-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.insert` is an [in-place operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516889/python-insert-not-getting-desired-results) and returns `None`. Instead, you can use a list comprehension:

```
L = [[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]

res = [[i, j, 'one'] for i, j in L]

print(res)

[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code as below :

```
list1=[[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]

for subList in list1:
    subList.append("one")

print list1
```

Output is :

```
[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
list1=[[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]

for l in list1:
    l.append("one")
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use list comprehension

```
>>> list1 = [[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
>>> [e + ['one'] for e in list1]
[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `list.insert()` function modifies the list without returning it.

You should print the list afterwards:

```
for list2 in list1:
    list2.insert(2,"one")
print(list1)
```

Alternatively, what you want to do can be more easily achieved with list comprehension:

```
list1=[[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
list2=[i + ["one"] for i in list1]
print(list2)
```

Both pf the above output:

```
[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `list.insert` in python [does not return any value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm). So your code inserts value to list correctly but you try to print this list wrong way. It should be:

```
for list2 in list1:
    list2.insert(2,"one")
    print list2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List_1 = [[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]  
List_2 = [ ]
For i in List_1:             #Selecting a sub-list at each iteration
    temp = i.append('one')   #Adding 'one' to the sub-list
    List_2.append()          #Adding the modified sublist to List_2
```

Result:

```
Print(List_2)    
[[2, 3, 'one'], [4, 5, 'one'], [6, 7, 'one']]
```